# Updating bootstrap dropdown with js

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I can set the value of this combobox to 4, the combobox has two elements (2,4). If i print out the value of the combobox, it says it has changed to 4 as intended; but on the actual web page the combobox stays the same. I tried dispatching an input event but that didn't work

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('gadget-iframe-0');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var quantity = innerDoc.getElementsByClassName("dropdown ng-isolate-scope ng-valid ng-dirty")[1];

console.log(quantity.value);
cvv_content.value = cvv;
quantity.value = 4;
```

[image]

[image: Quantity box on webpage]

How do I update the value & combobox so that it updates on the page?

Comment: Do you want to change the `innerText` ("2", "4") of the dropdown elements or change which element is selected? For the latter, you would do something like `quantity.classList.add('selected');`

Comment: is this all code in screen shoot ?
can't get what you want actually want.
if you are using angular then you can set quantity from .ts file

Comment: It is a dropdown on a webpage, I'm trying to change the dropdown's currently selected element from 2 to 4 via a chrome extension, the code is just a snippet.